# image width increases when inserting picture in word and converting to html

Tags: html, ms-word

i have searched everywhere regarding the increase of image width after inserting in word and converting to html , but i have still got no clue why does increase in width and height of image   occures when converting from word to html , i have inserted a  270px * 343px image in word but when i convert it  to html , the image width is  360px and height is 450px , i would like my image width to be 270px and height to be 343px itself, Is there anyway i can retain the image width and height ? Any help will be grateful

EDIT:
I have just inserted a image in word and then converted it to html . converted html file has increased  image width and height

Is there any way i can get the required 270px * 343px  output for my image if i convert word file to html ?

Comment: what did you have done so far? show us some code

Comment: Word does all kinds of things that it feels are better for you whether you like it or not, this is likely one of those scenarios. Easy answer, seriously don't use Word to create HTML documents. There are thousands of tutorials on how to create web pages for beginners, the tools to do so are free. Word is a word processor, it's meant to type letters and resumes, just because it does all this other crap doesn't mean it should or that it is good at it. Use the correct tools for the job.

Comment: What Rick says. Word is a poor choice of HTML editor.

Answer (score 0):

Its because Word does not support the image to be converted exactly as it is in html file. If you want exact pixels of you image you have to use other html editors like notepad, dreamweaver etc.

They are not as difficult as word and they will solve your problem and the image size will be exactly as 270px * 343px